# Add custom Font to .NET Core 2.0 Angular

Tags: css, angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.0 app using the Angular 2 Template.

The problem is that I can't add a custom font (woff2) to the app.component.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FrutigerBold';
    src: url("./assets/fonts/frutiger65_bold.woff2") format('woff2');
}
```

And get the following error:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module parse failed: C:\Users\gbuenrostro\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SecurityAngular\SecurityAngular\ClientApp\app\assets\fonts\frutiger65_bold.woff2 Unexpected character '�' (1:4)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)

Any ideas?

This is the Project:

[image]

Comment: Where is that error appearing?  In browser console or during build or at runtime?

Comment: It happens during angular build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the css in your app.component.css.
Create a file.css to include the font (not put then in asset folder) and change the webpack.config.vendor adding the file in nonTreeShakableModules

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    ...
    'file.css',
    ...
];
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that whenever I want to change something in that file.css the changes won't reflect in the project, having to recompile the vendor css.

Comment: what about include the font in the index.html?